# Como abrir un Modal, en CRUD de datos con jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, crud, tabla-dinámica

Tengo un CRUD de DATOS, en el que intento hacerlo algo interactivo con jQuery:

Esta es la parte de la tabla, en la que contiene los datos, y sus botones de editar, ver etc.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
<td>' .$row[npedido]. '</td>
<td>' .$row[fecha]. '</td>
<td>' .$row[cod_cliente]. '</td>
<td>' .$row[nombre_cliente]. '</td>
<td>' .$row[referencia]. '</td>
<td>' .$row[detalles]. '</td>
<td>' .$row[tipo]. '</td>
<td><i id="'.$row[npedido].'" class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
<td><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></td>
<td><i class="fas fa-print"></i></td>
<td><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
```

Estoy probando con el botón editar, al que le he asignado, al icono de editar, la "id" del pedido correspondiente.

¿Que intento conseguir ahora?
* Que al darle click, se abra un "Modal" con los datos para editar.

El modal, ya lo tengo preparado.

- He probado algunas cosas con jquery, como intentar llamarlo desde la clase, pero no me funciona:

> ```
> $( ".fa-edit" ).click(function() {
>   $('#editarPedido').show();
> });
> ```

¿Algún consejo, recomendación o aporte?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Podrías añadir el codigo html que tienes para el modal?

Comment: Amigo, acabo de solucionarlo de la siguiente forma: $(document).on('click', '.editar', function () {
  $('#edicionPedido').show();
}); Voy a añadirlo en una respuesta por si a alguien le sucede, y que también puedas comprobarlo.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solución de la siguiente forma:

> $(document).on('click', '.editar', function () {
>   $('#edicionPedido').show(); });

Simplemente, he modificado un poco el jQuery, para acceder con un click a la clase editar.

Esta clase le he añadido en el php de la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
<td><i id="'.$row[npedido].'" class="fas fa-edit editar"></i></td>
```

Espero que a alguien más también le pueda servir de ayuda.

Comment: Esta respuesta no es válida, ya que estás realizando lo mismo en la respuesta que en la pregunta, salvo que que ha cambiado el nombre del id del modal. Algo más debes de haber realizado, porque la llamada a los eventos mediante jQuery es la misma. Junto con que, da igual añadir la clase editar o lanzarlo mediante la clase fa-edit.

Comment: Hola, debes fijarte bien, en la primera línea del jQuery, ya que no es exactamente igual, el cambio es mínimo. Después, la línea de la tabla, he añadido la clase .editar, y con esto ha sido suficiente para funcionar, es cierto que hay más código, pero ya no es para esto, dentro de este jQuery, tengo una función de Ajax, que recibe el dato de esa ID en una variable, y la utilizo en una consulta sql para mostrar en el modal el pedido correspondiente.